# Create jsp to generate Out Of Memory

Tags: jsp, out-of-memory, war

I want to create war application to generate out of memory in a application server.
I see this code. How can I compile in a jsp in a war?
Thanks

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class TestOome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2^20];
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            while (true) {
                list.add("Lollygobblenlissbomb");
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            buffer = null;
            System.err.println(t + " in " + (end-start) + " millis.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Learn about servlets. JSPs should be used to generate HTML pages. Not to run arbitrary Java code. Googling for "Java servlet tutorial" will, I'm sure, give you back hundreds of results. I fail to see the point in generating an OOME on a server, though. What are you trying to achieve or demonstrate?

Comment: Thanks for response. 
I'm system admnistrator, not developer. Excuse for ask a simple question.
I want to test automatic generation of coredumps when a server have an Out Of Memory.
I'm reading about create a servlet. Thanks

Comment: The JVM won't crash with a core dump when an OOME happens. It will simply generate a stack trace like for any other exception.

Comment: So I want to capture heapdump in the moment of oom. There are options in jvm to make this. Is very usefull. Finally I read a tutorial and made a library and a simple application with maven to generate oom and it works like I want. 
Thanks!